# Java can't find gnu.io in RXTXcomm.jar, "test01.java:4: error: package gnu.io does not exist"

Tags: java, windows, import

Note: I have formatted this entire post as code as the checking algorithm insisted that "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please ..." and I could not figure out how to turn the check off, or what part of the post it was complaining about.
    Hi,

```
Sorry if I have made a dumb noob mistake, but I am really tearing my hair out over this problem.

I need to download waveform data from older oscilloscopes over a serial port to Windows 10 and iOS machines.
I did this quite easily on both platforms using python, but as I want to deploy this on a number of lab machines, I have decided to redo it in Java.
As Java does not have "inbuilt" support for serial comms, I am trying to use RXTXcomm and am writing the code on a Windows 10 machine.

To an attempt to try and get the RXTXcomm working I have made everything a simple as possible.

Environment;
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
PATH includes; 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Test directory;
c:\Users\gcollins1\Dropbox\SWDev\Java\test

Contents of the test directory;
08/12/2008  07:45 PM            60,984 RXTXcomm.jar
29/11/2019  01:04 PM                77 Test01.java

The file Test01.java contains;
// Check import works
import java.io
// we need gnu.io
import gnu.io

In a command prompt window if I run c:\Users\gcollins1\Dropbox\SWDev\Java\test>java test01.java
I get:
test01.java:4: error: package gnu.io does not exist
import gnu.io.*;
^
1 error
error: compilation failed

I get the same error if I include a local directory (".") classpath:
c:\Users\gcollins1\Dropbox\SWDev\Java\test>java -classpath .:RXTXcomm.jar test01.java

If I examine RXTXcomm.jar I see:
gnu
\io
\CommDriver.class and lots of other class files

I have put a copy of RXTXcomm.jar in every bin, ext and lib folder I can find, but this has not helped.
Searching for a solution is problematic, a lot of the solutions are JRE or third party Java specific.

Obviously RXTXcomm is used extensively by others so I must be making a real fundamental mistake?

It should not be this hard. SIGH!

Many thanks,

Garry
```

Comment: This is a classpath problem which is common for new programmers. You will save yourself a lot of time by reading up on the classpath concept now.

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn. Many thanks for your reply. I know that classpath can be a problem, so I have left it unset, i.e. the default which is "." or the current directory. The jar is in the directory I am running from, that is the "." directory, but I also tried specifying the containing directory with -classpath .:RXTXcomm.jar and the full path,  -classpath "c:\Users\gcollins1\Dropbox\SWDev\Java\Code_Java:RXTXcomm.jar" test01.java. I would have thought that this would have been sufficient? Again, many thanks.

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn. Following up I find that Windows will fail silently if the cp variable uses a ":". Now that I am using a ";" the cp statement seems to work ok. Still not 100% sure why I need the cp statement but I am at least running the code. Many thanks, Garry

Comment: This is why you need to read up on the classpath concept.  Under Windows, the separator is a semicolon, not a colon.

Comment: I though I had, but the two sources I used both used colons, and nowhere mentioned that this differed for windows. I am still at a loss to understand why I need the cp qualifier anyway, given that the .jar file is in the directory. Many thanks, Garry

Comment: You're welcome.  Class path issues are notoriously hard (as you are only told things don't work) especially for beginners, but is essential to any non-trivial Java development.